# Solspace Facebook Connect : Implementing syncing accounts for existing EE members

Tags: solspace-facebookconnect

I am the implementing Facebook Connect module for an existing site that already has a considerable number of registered users. As it's my first time using the module I have a couple of questions on best approach.

1. What is the best way to have existing members sync their accounts? Do I simply use the Login button? Is this context sensitive and will know if the user has already synced accounts and so not launch the whole agree to the app part?
2. How can I check if a user has already synced their EE account with their FB account? I would like a method of prompting users that have not synced to do so but also not bother those that already have.
3. How do I let users un-sync their accounts? I've noticed that if I sync my own account the app replaces my email address with my FB address. If I un-sync will it add back my old email address?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of digging around in the documentation got me some answers:

1. The login button is clever enough to know if you a user has already synced accounts.
2. `{exp:fbc:login_status}
   {if fbc_logged_into_facebook_and_ee == "y"}`
3. `{exp:fbc:account_sync_form
   return_when_unsynced="account/profile"
   }
   <input type="checkbox" name="unsync" id="unsync" value="yes">`